# Android: Update Image Uri in Intent of ShareActionProvider

Tags: android, android-intent, android-imageview, shareactionprovider

I have Two Applications, and I need to share data (Text and Image) from one to another. Everything works fine, except, if I change image after changing text (I upload photo after typing the text, or I reupload the image after typing the text) , my image does not update in second Application. I need something like TextWatcher for ImageView. Any ideas ?

Here is the important parts of my 1st Application:

Uri imageUri;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
                mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(setShareIntent());
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.layout_menu, menu);

    MenuItem share = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(share);
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(setShareIntent());
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    setMessageIntent();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private Intent setShareIntent() {
    String share = message.getText().toString();
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
    if (imageUri != null) {
        shareIntent.setType("image/png");
    } else {
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    }
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Here goes my sharing");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, share);
    return shareIntent;
}

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                imageUri = data.getData();
                String[] path = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imageUri, path, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(path[0]);
                String imgString = cursor.getString(index);
                image.setImageURI(imageUri);
                break;

    }

}
```

And here is my 2nd Application, where I share the data:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent receiver = getIntent();
    String received_text = receiver.getStringExtra(receiver.EXTRA_TEXT);

    Uri imageUri = (Uri) receiver.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    if (imageUri != null) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
    if (received_text != null) {
        text.setText(received_text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if doing so was stupid and can cause problems in further, but right now it works perfectly fine. If Anyone think this was a bad idea, tell me why, please. 
This is what I had done:

1. I declared shareIntent as Global.
2. I put imageUrl in intent also after uploading a new photo
3. I put imageUrl in intent in afterTextChanged() function, so everytime I change my text, my new imageUri will be set too.

Answer (score 0):

When first time upload image to another application, its time onCreate method first time call in second application after you second time image call from first application to another that time if second application is already created that time does not call onCrete so its better for onResume method for you.

Comment: the problem is in my 1st application, cause imageUrl doesn't change. it changes only when I change the text, cause I set intent into ShareActionProvider there and also in OnCreateOptionMenu.

Comment: set Log when you set Image URI in intent and also onActivityResult.